# Betrayal at house on the hill question about monster turns

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

In the betrayal at house on the hill rule book it says the traitor gets an extra turn on the monsters turn but what if there are no monsters in that haunt does the traitor still get the extra turn? Also is there a post somewhere that could help balance some of the haunts?

Comment: Could you add a quote from the rule book that leads you to think the traitor gets an extra turn?

Comment: Asking about balancing haunts is probably best as a new question (with more information about what sort of balance issues you are wanting to solve).

Answer (score 4):

The traitor does not get an "extra" turn. Rather, he gets a turn to control his own character, and then the monsters get a turn, in which the traitor controls what they do. So if there are no monsters in a given scenario, then the traitor just takes his normal turn, once, and nothing happens on the "monster turn".

Rule quote:

> After the traitor’s turn, any monsters
>   controlled by the traitor get a monster turn. (This means that the traitor gets two turns: one
>   for his or her actions and one for the monsters.) Then the first hero to the left of the traitor
>   takes a turn, and so on.

So while it does describe the traitor as getting "two turns", it is also clear that the "second turn" is the monsters' turn, not actually the traitor's turn.